# Why does chrome "refuse to apply inline style" in jQuery with Content Security Policy set to self and hash

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, content-security-policy

I have a bootstrap site that uses jQuery v3.4.0 (3.3.x had same problem).
Header from the site with **content security policy** looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2275
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: image/png; style-src 'self' 'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: image/png; style-src 'self' 'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Vary: Cookie
Server: Werkzeug/0.15.1 Python/3.6.7
Date: Sat, 27 Apr 2019 21:37:07 GMT
```

All of my scripts are **hosted locally** (so 'self' should suffice), **no inline scripts** or **style attributes** are used in the site itself, but chrome still generates good amount of errors:
[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsQ0r.png), 
[screenshot with non-minifed version of jQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTScL.png)

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

As you can see, I also added the hash that chrome itself has generated to the CSP, but no matter what I change ( also tried adding that hash to 'script-src') I still get the same type of errors.

There are many similar questions about chrome and CSP but none of them has answered why would chrome forbid a script to edit styles when it should be permitted by 'self' or the hash.

Answer (score 0):

If you do set 'unsafe-inline' it'll probably work. I realize that is not what you want to allow though. JQuery is probably using unsafe inline styles.

I'm very tired atm, but if you want to give this a read you might find your answer: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3541

Also, where is it documented that you can specify allowed MIME types for data uri's? I have never seen `img-src 'self' data: image/png;`. Shouldn't it just be `img-src 'self' data:;`?